# Json response issue

Tags: json

I have this response

> { "id": "A148FD5E57B14254B30012BDFA8DB6BE", "key": 8, "address_1":
>   "ILFORD ILFORD CASTLEVIEW GARDENS", "address_2": "GREATER LONDON",
>   "prop_type": "T", "lease_type": "F", "sale_price": "270455", "lat":
>   "51.5756245", "lng": "0.0589847", "paon": "", "saon": "36",
>   "sale_history": [ { "key": 8, "sale_date": "270455", "sale_price":
>   "2005-05-27" } ] }, { "id": "8FF1C0D6DC434FC4849BCD09AAFE9DE1", "key":
>   20, "address_1": "ILFORD ILFORD CASTLEVIEW GARDENS", "address_2":
>   "GREATER LONDON", "prop_type": "T", "lease_type": "F", "sale_price":
>   "135000", "lat": "51.5756245", "lng": "0.0589847", "paon": "", "saon":
>   "36", "sale_history": [ { "key": 20, "sale_date": "135000",
>   "sale_price": "1999-05-27" } ] }

but I wanted to convert it like this

```
"my_property": {
    "id": "1A936E79FB2042D087D56F98346A24D1",
    "address_1": "CASTLEVIEW GARDENS, ILFORD",
    "address_2": "ILFORD, IG1 3QB",
    "current_estimated": "$232323",
    "price_change_amount": "$23",
    "price_change_percentage": "+12%",
    "avg_pcm_growth_amount": "$342",
    "avg_pcm_growth_percentage": "23%",
    "prop_type": "Flat",
    "lease_type": "Lease",
    "new_not": "N",
    "sale_price": "$275000",
    "sale_date": "2014-08-22",
    "lat": "51.5755682",
    "lng": "0.0534691",
    "sales_history": [
      {
        "sale_date": "2 Dec, 2011",
        "sale_price": "$2123123",
        "price_change_percentage": "+22.2%"
      },
      {
        "sale_date": "2 Dec, 2013",
        "sale_price": "$23432423",
        "price_change_percentage": "+1.2%"
      }
    ]
  },
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: First, your own string is not the true json syntax. Second, which langauge are you using? Most languages have provided a lib to easily edit json string.

Answer (score -1):

As @vonfry points out :  `"my_property": { "id":` is not valid json.

You would have to put my_property inside another object, eg. in javascript:
 `var my_obj = { "my_property": { "id": ... } }`

Perhaps I am wrong but it looks to me as though you want to produce a new object based on the received json. So maybe you want:

```
var received = { "id" : ... } // Your received json
var my_property = {};
my_property.id = received.id;
my_property.address_1 = received.address_1;
//And so on for the properties you want to copy from the received object
my_property.current_estimated = "$232323";
//And so on for the extra fields you want to assosciate with my_property
```

Incidentally I guess `"sale_history": [ { "key": 8, "sale_date": "270455", "sale_price": "2005-05-27" } ]` should be:
`"sale_history": [ { "key": 8, "sale_price": "270455", "sale_date": "2005-05-27" } ]`